# How to read in an XLS tab with two potential names?

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am using the `XLConnect` package in R to read in .xlsx workbooks based on tab name. There are two variations in tab name I would like to read in ("All Sales" OR "Tot Sales"). I need to select either term because some months are named inconsistently.

```
  # Set Workbook
  xls <- loadWorkbook("mydoc.xlsx"))

  # Read in Worksheet
  wks <- readWorksheet(xls,sheet = grep("All Sales|Tot Sales"))
```

This yields the following error:

> Error in grep("All Sales|Tot Sales") :
>         argument "x" is missing, with no default

How do I return either name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the required x (where to search for the pattern) argument.

```
  # Set Workbook
  xls <- loadWorkbook("mydoc.xlsx")

  # Read in Worksheet
  wks <- readWorksheet(xls,sheet = grep("All Sales|Tot Sales", getSheets(xls)))
```

Comment: Sumedh, that worked for me! I couldn't figure out what went into the x (where to search). Thank you! I will accept your answer shortly!